# Run multiple queries where all succeed or all fail

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, atomic

I need to update 2 rows in to 2 different tables then insert a new row in to another different table which must be done so either they all succeed or fail. (I think the word is atomically?). I did some searching but can only seem to find questions related to doing multiple inserts or updates to one table.

Below are the 3 queries I need to run:

```
UPDATE submission SET status='a' WHERE idgreg = 119 AND status='p' AND userid = 126;

UPDATE greg SET iscomplete=1 WHERE idgreg = 119;

INSERT INTO completion (idperson, idgreg, datecompleted, idsubmission, mediaid, description, 
privatestatus, contenttype, totalamount)  
SELECT s.idperson, s.idgreg, s.datesubmitted, s.idsubmission, COALESCE(s.youtubeid, s.contentid) AS mediaidid, g.description, g.privatestatus, 
g.contenttype, COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS totalamount 
FROM submission s 
INNER JOIN greg g on s.idgreg = g.idgreg 
INNER JOIN contribution c on s.idgreg = c.idgreg 
WHERE s.idsubmission = 36 AND c.ispaid = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your queries inside a MySQL *transaction* to ensure that they execute atomically.  But first, declare error handlers which will `ROLLBACK` all changes in the event of an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE runYourQueries()

BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE submission SET status='a' WHERE idgreg = 119 AND status='p' AND userid = 126;

UPDATE greg SET iscomplete=1 WHERE idgreg = 119;

INSERT INTO completion (idperson, idgreg, datecompleted, idsubmission, mediaid, description,
    privatestatus, contenttype, totalamount)  
SELECT s.idperson, s.idgreg, s.datesubmitted, s.idsubmission,
    COALESCE(s.youtubeid, s.contentid) AS mediaidid, g.description, g.privatestatus,
    g.contenttype, COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS totalamount 
FROM submission s 
INNER JOIN greg g on s.idgreg = g.idgreg 
INNER JOIN contribution c on s.idgreg = c.idgreg 
WHERE s.idsubmission = 36 AND c.ispaid = 1;

COMMIT;

END
```

Comment: This didn't work. I purposely made one of them fail and the other 2 queries still updated. I added a picture to my main question to show what happened. Any ideas?

Comment: You must have a choosen a **transactional** engine like *InnoDb*. See the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Comment: @Mitchell You should use a stored procedure in order to take advantage of `ROLLBACK`, which will undo everything in the event of an error.

Comment: I am using InnoDB. Okay going over this now, will return when I've got it working or not

Comment: I am getting an error from having the DECLARES before defining the procedure. However, if I put the DECLARES after BEGIN I don't get any. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mitchell Yes, you are correct, sorry for the typo.